# How to get JS ondragend event.pageY to not include toolbars (Firefox)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the X and Y position of the mouse in a div for both JavaScript ondragstart and ondragend but they produce different results.

The ondragstart function works as expected however onDragEnd is broken (says browser window rather than div).

What's happening is that ondragend pageX/Y is counting the menu bars and bookmarks bar. The same thing happens if I use clientX/Y instead of pageX/Y.

It's happening on both Firefox desktop Linux Mint and Windows 10.

```js
window.ondragstart = function(event) {
  console.log(event.pageY); // works
}
window.ondragend = function(event) {
  console.log(event.pageY); // different!
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" style="width: 100%; height: 560px; border: 1px solid black;">
</div>
```

If I learned jQuery would it fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a 13 year old bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521

A work around is to use ondragover rather than ondragend:

JS

```
<script>
window.ondragstart = function(event) {
  console.log(event.pageY); // works
}
window.ondragover = function(event) {
  console.log(event.pageY); // works!
}
</script>
```

ondragover produces the correct results on Firefox (Linux + Win10) and Win 10 Edge.